# Unsupported Web Browser

Tags: c#, plugins, browser, web

I am trying to make a simple application with a web browser that will log me into www.icloud.com. and display the page on a Windows form. When I launch the application and try to load the page it tells me the browser is not supported. I have tried using the GeckoFX method and one other I can't remember off hand with no avail. I think the reason for the unsupported browser is due to plugins, but I am not sure. I am new to importing web browser functionality into an application so any help would be great! Thanks!

~Chris.

Comment: Which web browser are you using for this task?

Comment: The default one that comes with Visual studio. I assume it is Internet explorer. I have even tried changing the registry to another IE version, but this didn't work.

Comment: Well the default one that visual studio uses. I am very new to this so I am sorry if my answer was stupid or not informative enough.

Comment: What Visual Studio and Windows versions you have?

Comment: Visual studio 2010 ultimate and windows 7

Comment: I'm doing all this in C# by the way.

Comment: Anyone know how to fix this? I tried to change the default browser to chrome, but it still get the message "Unsupported Browser"

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/688/unsupported.jpg/